# Are resources global in scope in a C++ (VS) program and consequently where is the ideal place to load a list into a combo box?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using a resource file for my dialog boxes, menus, etc. in a C++ program in Visual Studio.  Just wondering if a resource file has a global scope?  Also, as a consequence of this, where is the ideal place in the program to call GetDlgItem to get the handle of a combobox and to load its list (as well as other similar tasks)?

Can someone give a simple example of adding a list item to a combo box in the context in which a resource file is being used rather than a when a combo box created explicitly in the code is being used?

Comment: There are 2 parts to Windows resources (1) the compiled .res file and (2) the generated .h file.  The .res file is appended to the executable. The .h file is compiled into the program and `#define`s symbols that can be used later in the running program to load resources.  Resources like Dialogs, Menus, etc are loaded and unloaded by the program.  [`GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) can only be called after a Dialog has been loaded as it takes a `hDlg` as it's first parameter.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  1) So by "loaded" you mean once the resource.h file has been processed? 2) Is it a best practice to take care of this kind of thing in wWinMain or can entries in a combo box be handled in the resource files themselves?

Comment: There is a lot of information and some example code in the documentation here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/finding-and-loading-resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/finding-and-loading-resources)

Comment: (1) re: _"loaded"_ No see above comment by @drescherjm and also [`CreateDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga). (2) No dialogs are temporary things (their resource file definition is basically a template for a dialog) and their controls only exist when then dialog is being shown.  Initialisation of controls on Dialogs is usually done by handling the [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog) message which is sent to dialog callback immediately prior to the dialog being made visible.

Comment: Sorry, cut my teeth on Ansi C, but trying to get up to speed on Visual C++ at the moment.  I have a dialog box that is created by DialogBox().  It has a combo box that I need to fill.  But I can't seem to grab the handle of the combo box from WM_INITDIALOG case in the message handler.

Comment: To be a bit more explicit: resources can be appended to executables (.EXE) and DLL's. This matters when you're loading a resource; you might need to specify where it comes from. `HMODULE=NULL` is the default (from the EXE which started the process). Hence the scope is technically not "global" but "module".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information given in the comments answered the question sufficiently.  What initially prompted the question was my desire and attempts to put items in a combo box list.  The code below successfully accomplished this.  This is mostly a Visual C++ autogenerated message handling procedure for a drop down menu entry called "Add" under a main menu "Edit."  In the dialog generated by selecting Add there is a combo box which is designated here as IDC_COMBO1. (IDC_COMBO1 is the name given to the combobox in the resource file and is defined in resource.h so it is recognized here.) I added three lines to the code to put the entry "1st" into the combo box list.  Also, as suggested by Richard Critten, I handled this in the WM_INITDIALOG message case which makes sense beside being simple and concise.  The three lines were:

```
HWND hWndCB1;
hWndCB1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_COMBO1);
SendMessage(hWndCB1, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("1st"));
```

The entry "1st" appeared in the list when I built the project.  Thanks to those who commented, and I hope that this helps someone else who is attempting to accomplish this.  The code of the message handling procedure is below.

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK Add(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HWND hWndCB1;

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {   
            hWndCB1 = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_COMBO1);
            SendMessage(hWndCB1, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)TEXT("1st"));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE; 
        }
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```